# Tool for extracting table and commands performed on them from PL SQL code

Tags: oracle, parsing, plsql

I am looking for a tool or online resource which when given a PL/SQL code gives information about tables on which `insert` , `select` , `update` and `delete` are performed.

e.g:

```
TABLE   SELECT  INSERT  UPDATE  DELETE

v_empl   Yes      Yes    No       No
```

Comment: You may use `TRIGGER` to log the DMLs used on another table,  but not `SELECT` queries.

Comment: You will have to set up a universal audit entry table and set triggers on the tables which you want to keep audits for. If you want the detailed solution on this, I would like to post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Should it be static i.e. source based or dynamic(based on workload)?

Look at this grammar for PL/SQL:
https://github.com/patrick133t/PLSQL

And this SQL grammar:
https://github.com/porcelli/plsql-parser

With some tweaking you will be able to extract all SQL statements from PL/SQL code and all table references from all SQL statements.

Also look at `DBA_DEPENDENCIES` view. Oracle maintains similar information internally.

Also note that there are statements like `insert "from" select` or updatable joins, so sometimes it is non-trivial to identify source and target table.